# Filling an array + 2 with objects

Tags: arrays, json, swift, object, entities

I have an entity called Car where we can find multiple attributes + Owner (User => another entity)

EX :

```
 class Car: NSObject {
var Id : String!

var Latitude : String?
var Longitude : String?
var Model : String?
var Name : String?
var Owner : User!    }
```

And I have a Json filled with all the cars .

so I want to create an array with these diffent cars from JSON .

I'm using Alamofire to communicate with a REST API

and that's what I'm doing :

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "------ URL -------", parameters:nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.debugDescription)   // result of response serialization

            if (response.result.isSuccess)
            {
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                      print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    ===> Here I have the JSON with the different cars .
                    // here i'm cleaning the response 
                    self.arrayCarsFromJson=JSON.objectForKey("Result") as! NSArray

                        for index in 0...self.arrayCarsFromJson.count-1{


              // here I'm taking every car by it's own . to create my entity 

                       self.dictionnaryCars = self.arrayCarsFromJson.objectAtIndex(index) as! NSDictionary


           self.car.Id = self.dictionnaryCars.objectForKey("Id") as! String
```

// for all the entities

and finally

```
              // I'm adding every car in an Array of cars and this is my declaration for this array above    => private var cars = [Car]()
    to do so :                                 self.cars.append(self.car)} // end of loop (for)
```

===================>>>>>>> Result

I found in the console that I have the good number of elements in self.cars 
but all the elements are filled with the same final car in the JSON list.

when I tried to find out what's happening in the loop I have made

```
print(self.cars)
```

And I found out that the system is doing great for the first car,
and then for the second: the system replace the first car with the second and he add a new element for the second car two so in the second loop instruction I found an array of two element filled with the second car, second car.

And for the Third is the same thing happening: third car, third car, third car
4th: 4th car, 4th car, 4th car, 4th car....

Comment: Hi. Please don't get into the habit of requesting urgency here - remember that everyone here is a volunteer. Thanks!

Comment: Could you format your question a bit? BTW I think it's probably about  `self.dictionnaryCars = self.arrayCarsFromJson.objectAtIndex(index)`

Comment: @halfer : Yep sorry for that .

Comment: @FranMowinckel :I need to  extract the entity Car from the JSON
In my JSON I have multiple cars so I'm Browsing the hole JSON one by One in a loop and creating my entity car on every instruction and then to fill all the cars in array of type Car.
Final desired result:car1 , car2 , car3 , car4 
but what I've found is : car4 , car4 , car4,car4
self.dictionnaryCars = self.arrayCarsFromJson.objectAtIndex(index) 
in this line I'm just extrating the JSON in dictionnary to get the  access for every car by it's own, and it work right I even retaest it right now .
And thanks very much for your response

Comment: So you assign `self.car.Id` and then you append it to an array `self.cars.append(self.car)`? it looks like you're adding the same object and then it's normal that you have `car4, car4, ...`. Try this: `self.cars = Array(Set(self.cars))` and then count the objects.

Comment: That an exemple of my code :
for index in 0...self.array.count-1
{
self.SingleCarDictionary = self.JSON.ObjectAtIndex(index)
self.car.Id = self.SingleCarDictionary.ObjectForKey(""Id)
... and for all the attributes


//Then I add this car to an array of cars 
self.cars.append(self.car)
}

Comment: That an exemple of my code :
for index in 0...self.array.count-1
{
self.SingleCarDictionary = self.JSON.ObjectAtIndex(index)
self.car.Id = self.SingleCarDictionary.ObjectForKey(""Id)
... and for all the attributes
//Then I add this car to an array of cars 
self.cars.append(self.car)
}
So in the loop (for ..) in every instruction (i +1) we have a new car from the JSON list
I tried to fill the array with string (like filling an array of string with car.Address) I found out that the result is good (final result an array with all the different address of cars)
>the problem is only with the entity

Comment: @FranMowinckel : The system always delete all the precedent cars and replace them with the last car  so in the final the result is a table filled with the last * number of cars

Comment: I mean that you're probably adding the very same element (entity / `car`) to the `cars` array and then modifying the attributes of that element. Where do you create `car`? (that should be added to the question). BTW it's easier/nicer to include a break point in code and see what's happening.

Comment: @FranMowinckel Can you please give a code exemple of filling an array with entities ? 
entity like this :
 class Car: NSObject {
var Id : String!

var Latitude : String?
var Longitude : String?
var Model : String?
var Name : String?
var Owner : User!    }  
Thanks